# extjs: Loading mask should come on top

Tags: extjs

In my application I have combobox, when I click on it, ajax call fetching data from server. At that time loading mask is not appearing on top, it appears behind the popup. How to get it on top of component.

```
xtype:'combobox', 
fieldLabel: 'Student Group(*)', 
editable:false, 
store: GroupStore, 
valueField:'name', 
displayField:'name', 
name: 'txtStudentGroup', 
id:'txtStudentGroupId', 
forceSelection:true, 
queryMode: 'local', 
triggerAction: 'all', 
emptyText:'Select Student Group',
```

Comment: please post the code responsible for the load mask config and your combo box config. It would also be helpful to see the owner container of the combo.

Comment: xtype:'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Student Group(*)',
editable:false,
store: GroupStore,
valueField:'name',
displayField:'name',
name: 'txtStudentGroup',
id:'txtStudentGroupId',
forceSelection:true,
queryMode: 'local',
triggerAction: 'all',
emptyText:'Select Student Group',

Comment: your query mode is local, why would it trigger an ajax call?